# JMS component - ConnectException for InOut pattern

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

I have a problem using the Apache Commons JMS component. If I use InOut exchange pattern to put the message in the queue and the JMS Server is down, I receive the java.net.ConnectException with recovery attempts being made every 5000 ms. I assume that Camel implicitly creates a consumer endpoint to listen to the replyTo queue, so I'm not sure if it's possible to disable this behavior.

Is there a way to disable the recovery in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a camel groovy route. Hope it solves your problem.

```
from("jms:queue:TEST?disableReplyTo=true")
    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
    /*Do Processing*/
    .inOnly("jms:queue:TEST")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the current Message Exchange Pattern is `InOut` the JMS Component expects a reply message. If you would like to send a "fire-and-forget" message to JMS component you need to change the MEP first to `InOnly`.

Example:

```
.to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "activemq:somequeue")
```